# Service Broker does not notify about changes taking place between unsuscribing and re-wiring to the SqlDependency.OnChange event

Tags: c#, sql-server, service-broker

I have this code:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string _connectionString = @"Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=MyDatabase; User Id=sa; Password=test";
        //private SqlCommand _command;
        //private SqlConnection _connection;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Notify(Object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs args)
        {
            var obj = sender as SqlDependency;
            obj.OnChange -= Notify;

            Listen();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDependency.Start(_connectionString,"CacheQueue");
            Listen();
        }

        private void Listen()
        {
            using (var _connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                _connection.Open();

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
                    @"SELECT [C1] ,[C2],[C3] FROM [dbo].[Table]",
                    _connection))
                {

                    SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command, "Service=CacheService", 0);

                    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(Notify);

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDependency.Stop(_connectionString, "CacheQueue");
        }
    }
```

I am using SQL Server 2008 Express Edition and I am testing on my local machine. In SQL Server i executed the following statements:

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET ENABLE_BROKER;

CREATE QUEUE CacheQueue;

CREATE SERVICE CacheService
  ON QUEUE CacheQueue
([http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/PostQueryNotification]);
```

If I execute multiple updates on table "Table" between receiving the first notification and re-wiring to the OnChange event I don't receive any other notifications.

For example, let's say that I run this statement in SQL Server:

```
UPDATE [Table] 
SET C1 = 'aaaa'
WHERE Id = 7 -- an existing Id
```

After that, I receive the notification and the "Notify" event handler is fired. But if I stay with a breakpoint in it and I go back to SQL and I execute other DML statements on the same table, I don't get any notifications. My expectation was that after re-wiring to OnChange event I would be able to get all changes that happened in the meantime. Aren't they kept in a queue in Service Broker? How can I achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has actually nothing to do with Service Broker. It is all about [Query Notifications](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175110(v=sql.105).aspx), an unrelated feature that *uses* Service Broker to deliver its notifications. Please read [The Mysterious Notification](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/) to understand what we're talking about.

You must understand what Query Notifications do: it allows a client application to be notified when the **result of a query changes**. It is, very specifically, **not** a change tracking mechanism. For change tracking use [Change Tracking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933875.aspx) or [Change Data Capture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645937.aspx).

As such, your expectations are unfounded. You should expect to be notified, once, after you submit a query. That's all there is.

Comment: In the meantime I've reached the same conclusion, Thank you for the answer.